# CSS3 multiple background images - support on mobile devices?

Tags: css, progressive-enhancement

Im mobile optimising my site with media queries. Is it safe to use multiple background images on the mobile optimised version? Mobile browsers are generally quite up to date so I would have thought this would be fine...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use multiple backgrounds. The support is up-to-date with modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds